# mysql 3 table join with update

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I am trying to update the status of a column, by checking two joined tables. Even though I dont get an error. The colum is not updating. I want to take the general blockplot id and see if there is a transaction that matches and or a a container. If there is a transaction but no container i need to mark it as P.

```
UPDATE (general
LEFT JOIN 
transactions 
ON 
general.blockplotid=transactions.blockplotid)
LEFT JOIN 
container 
ON 
general.blockplotid=container.blockplotid
SET general.lotstatus = 'P'
WHERE general.lotstatus != 'U' AND
transactions.id_transaction IS NOT NULL AND
container.id_container IS NULL
```

So summarize, I have 3 tables. I only want to update one colum in one table. I want to check for values in the other two tables, their values depend upon the set value. The three tables are connected with a primary key to foreign key.

When I do a double join select statement. The query seems correct.

```
SELECT transactions.blockplotid AS blockplotid_2, container.blockplotid AS blockplotid_1, general.blockplotid, general.lotstatus, container.id_container, transactions.id_transaction
FROM ((general LEFT JOIN transactions ON general.blockplotid=transactions.blockplotid) LEFT JOIN container ON general.blockplotid=container.blockplotid)
ORDER BY general.blockplotid ASC
```

However it seems as though the join for the update isnt like the select.

This query seemed to work:

This query worked:

```
UPDATE ((general LEFT JOIN transactions ON transactions.blockplotid=general.blockplotid) LEFT JOIN container ON container.blockplotid=general.blockplotid)
SET general.lotstatus='P'
WHERE general.blockplotid!='U'  AND container.id_container is null  AND transactions.id_transaction is not null
```

The difference here is the case of IS NOT NULL and also the order of the where condition.
Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: What if you remove the parentheses?

Comment: Doesnt update any rows. Doesnt return any errors either.

Comment: Are you sure that there's rows that match that condition?  What if you change the query from `update` to `select * from`?

Comment: i tested this and it returned 1,718 rows

Comment: Hmmm... any triggers on your `general` table?

Comment: it seemed to me when i tried to view the temporary table that is created, instead of there being null values, it seems that they are empty strings.

Comment: Looking at the records returned, they already have the status of P. i have screwed up something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the parentheses/locations of the joins. Try a setup like this:

```
UPDATE

Table1

SET

Table1

. Field1 = StagingTable . Field1

FROM

Table1

INNER JOIN StagingTable
ON Table1 . Field2 = StagingTable . Field2
WHERE

StagingTable . Field3 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest restructuring your UPDATE statement to have an embedded SUB-SELECT.  update general set lotstatus = (SELECT .... WHERE .... )